Solving a differential equation using separation of variables vs Integrating Factor. Difference in answer.
Solving as a variable separable equation:
$y'+16xy=6x \rightarrow y'=x(6-16y) \rightarrow \frac{1}{6-16y}dy=x$
integrating we obtain (using u=6-16y, dy=du/-16):
$\frac{-1}{16}\ln(6-16y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+C \rightarrow \ln(6-16y)=-8x^2-16C$
and so the solution is:
$$y=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{16}e^{-8x^2-16C}$$
But using an integrating factor we have: $y'+16xy=6x \rightarrow e^{8x^2}y'+e^{8x^2}16xy=e^{8x^2}6x \rightarrow [e^{8x^2}y]'=e^{8x^2}6x$.
Now integrating we have (using u=$8x^2$,dx=du/16x):
$e^{8x^2}y=\frac{3}{8}e^{8x^2}+C$
and the I.F. solution is:
$$y=\frac38+Ce^{-8x^2}$$
My answer using the variable separable method has been marked wrong, am I missing something? Does a comparison of the solutions from the two methods not simply imply that C is negative?

Note ... $$D:=-\frac{1}{16} e^{-16C}$$ is a constant.  And
$$
\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{16}e^{-8x^2-16C} = \frac38+De^{-8x^2}
$$
The only difference in the two solutions is that $C$ can have any sign, but $D<0$.  "Any sign" is the correct solution.  When you integrate to get a logarithm, two signs are possible: $\log(6-16y)$ and $\log(16y-6)$.

Thank you very much!
